# Does $AA^{-1}$ have the unique product property?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, geometric-group-theory

Let $A$ be a finite subset of a torsion free group $G$ with $|A|\geq3$. Does the set $AA^{-1}$ have the "unique product" property (i.e. there exist an element $c\in AA^{-1}$ that is uniquely written as a product $ab$ with $a\in A$, $b\in A^{-1}$)? In particular, what can we say if we consider the Passman four group: 
$$G:=\langle x,y: (x^2)^y=x^{-2}, (y^2)^x=y^{-2}\rangle$$

Comment: I suppose you already know that, but the answer is positive for abelian groups.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, the answer is positive for all right orderable groups containing Abelian ones.

Comment: Examples of torsion free groups without the UP property have been constrcuted by Rips and Segev. I would be suprised if they are not counter example to your question.https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869387901256

Comment: @Thomas,  no, Rips-Segev example won't work. The UP   propery is about the product of two different sets $ AB$ In the paper $B$ is of size 4, a concrete set.